Vertical linear gradient in Chartjs that follows data
In Chartsjs I can see how you make a vertical gradient thats not a problem. The issue with this approach is the gradient starts at a set point and then moves down, so any low valued data points would not see the gradient( red to transparent).
In the code below I am able to set the start point but I just cant get it to move to the next point and then fade down. My result is this

But what I want to replicate it this where the gradient follows the curve

 plugins: [
      {
        afterLayout: (chart) => {
          let ctx = chart.ctx;
          ctx.save();
          let xAxis = chart.scales['x'];
          let yAxis = chart.scales['y'];
          let gradient = ctx.createLinearGradient(0, yAxis.top, 0, yAxis.bottom);

          chart.data.datasets.forEach((dataSet) => {
            let color;
            const data = dataSet.data;
            data.forEach((v, index) => {
              let x = xAxis.getPixelForTick(index);
              const y = yAxis.getPixelForTick(index);
              let offset = (y - yAxis.top) / (yAxis.bottom - yAxis.top);
              offset = Math.max(0, Math.min(1, offset));
              let alpha = 1 - offset;
              let rgbValues = dataSet.borderColor.toString().match(/\d+/g);
              let color = `rgba(${rgbValues[0]}, ${rgbValues[1]}, ${rgbValues[2]}, ${alpha})`;
              if (color) {
                gradient.addColorStop(offset, color);
              }
            });
            dataSet.backgroundColor = gradient;
            ctx.restore();
          });
        },
        id: '',
      },
    ],

